# link erlang nif on windows

Tags: c, windows, erlang, cygwin

I try to compile a erlang nif plugin on windows using the cygwin gcc.
It compiles fine but the linker issues some errors:

undefined reference to `_enif_get_int'

I'm currently linking against ei.lib and erl_interface.lib.
None of these contain the required symbols. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks rather like you have a windows module (which expects symbols starting with underscore) linking against cygwin libraries (which typically don't export symbols with underscore).

Comment: I thought about this is well. But I listed the symbols in all the libs I could get my hands on and I didn't find anything similar - with or without underscore.

Comment: According to this you need the erl_nif library.  http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html

Comment: haven't found any library with the symbol and from the link you posted: gcc -fPIC -shared -o niftest.so niftest.c -I $ERL_ROOT/usr/include/ there is no library linked with the symbol :S